# Не получается установить numpy с помощью pip3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

```
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0o9fj9bx-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed

--compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/numpy

Storing debug log for failure in /home/daniil/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Какую команду запускали, как именно устанавливали, что в логах?

Comment: Такие вещи как `numpy` следует из бинарников устанавливать, если вы точно не знаете зачем вам нужна компиляция. Конкретный способ установки зависит от платформы, приведите вашу ОСь.